# Form submission is blocked while submitting the form in hubspot

Tags: javascript, css, hubspot

While submitting the form in hubspot I am getting the following error

```
Blocked form submission to '/_hcms/forms/submissions/v3/public/submit/formsnext/multipart/3906991/a5f4fa93-3011-4a50-9823-d872ed881a9e' 
because the form's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-forms' permission is not set.
```

Active resource loading counts reached to a per-frame limit while the tab is in background. Network requests will be delayed until a previous loading finishes, or the tab is foregrounded. See for more details

Even the JS file is linked with the form but I dont know why it's not working

Comment: Please add some code to define exact problem as its difficult to understand exact question you want to ask.like js or form html, etc

Answer (score 1):

After `version 69+` `Chrome` enabled a experimental feature called,
**Background Tab Resource Load Throttling** [link](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5527160148197376).

with this experimental feature if you switch tabs while your resources are loading or requests are sending, chrome will pause some of those requests. Once you go back to that tab they suppose to execute. that is not happening.

you can test this by playing a youtube video in a background. sometimes the video will stop playing. 
hope they will fix this with a new update. for now you can disable this feature by

```
chrome://flags/ 
search Throttling 
and disabling "Enable resource load throttling"
```

Hope it helps.